# detect a process running on the host into a docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

I have a docker container and my script is running inside it. The script detects if a chrome or firefox is running and then prints some log.

The script works perfectly on my host with the command pgrep firefox but the same doesnt work inside the container.

I have a situation due to which I need the docker container to know if firefox or chrome is running on the host.

I use this command to run my docker container :

> sudo docker run -ti --privileged --device /dev/snd:/dev/snd -v
>   /home/pravin:/home --net=host ubuntuv2 bash

I simply want my container to know the processes running on the host machine so that pgrep firefox command will give some output in the container terminal. How do I do it?

Comment: Docker is specifically designed to prevent this.  You might look at the `docker run` command you wound up with; just directly running the process as root on the host without Docker will be much simpler and not any less secure.

Answer (score 1):

So I was able to get it to work by adding a flag `--pid=host` to the command

so the final command

> sudo docker run --pid=host -ti --privileged --device /dev/snd:/dev/snd
>   -v /home/pravin:/home --net=host ubuntuv2 bash

Hence it detects a process running on the host inside the container